# What is the correct way to upgrade python?

Tags: python

I have python 2.7.6 and 3.4 on my mac installed currently. I want to upgrade python2 to python 2.7.8 as I believe it is the more secure. What is the right way to do this? Do I simply download the installer from the website and run it? If so, will my system automatically use 2.7.8 over the previously installed 2.7.6?

Note, the python version 2.7.6 came pre-installed. And I apologize if the question seems redundant. I used to develop blindly without any thought of the versions and packages and made a mess of my projects. So now I try to careful.

Comment: You're generally not supposed to touch the ones that were pre-installed, instead running new versions in a a virtual environment (`virtualenv`).

Comment: Avoid changing the pre-installed version of Python as the OS typically depends on it. Instead, consider installing 2.7.8 (e.g. as `python2.7.8`) and use a virtualenv to run that specific version of Python in your projects.

Answer (score 0):

`pyenv` is a simple Python version management. You can find more on [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv).